# Sync files from docker container to host using Dockerfile or docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I am just done with making an ubuntu container and copying the content from host(my local machine) to the the ubuntu container. But as I am making some directories/files in work directory in the container, I can see it is not getting synced to my the host folder, which I initially copied.

I want this sync as I use `docker system prune` or `docker rmi -f image_name` frequently for some testing purposes, which eventually deletes the content and then I have no backup of those files.

I have used `COPY` to copy files from host to container but need help with the reverse, so that it can happen automatically everytime before I delete the container/image.

Any working solution on this would be very appreciable.

Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
    ubuntu:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: ubuntu
        ports:
            - 8091
        volumes:
            - ./dir:/dir
volumes:
    dir:
        external: false
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /dir
VOLUME /dir

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y

EXPOSE 8000
COPY . .
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**Solution:**
I just found the solution

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```

This is the command which you need to use to copy content from container to the host machine.

Comment: What exactly is the directory you want to sync (bind mount)? It seems you used `./dir`, but want to share the entire hosts `.`?

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent I want to sync the content in ./dir. I have done from host to container(as shown) and now I want the reverse

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not an expert on compose, but it seems you cannot name bind mounts (which is what you want). So I believe you should remove the top-level `volumes` declaration, since you don't want a volume. The bind mount path needs to be absolute as well, at least in the world outside compose. Note that if the bind mount should work, you don't need any copy or reverse direction, it just syncs.

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent Whatever I have written it is written in the simplest way possible. I just need to sync the directories/files from my ubuntu container to my host container.

Comment: I just found the solution for this. I have updated the question

Comment: That is called copy. What one generally calls a *sync* is a bind mount in docker. Oddly enough, you seem to have started using a bind mount and then used a different method. In order to use `docker cp` you don't need to declare `/dir` a volume.

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container. Kindly try to understand the actual intent of my words. I WAS ACTUALLY LOOKING FOR A WAY TO DO THE REVERSE. I was looking to copy content from container to host. Anyways I have found the command to do that and that's working. Thanks for your time. The next I might want to do is making this command work before I exit the container. Do you have idea about that?

Comment: I want to run the command I have added in "Solution" part mention in the question I have asked above. Do you know how to execute that command when I am inside a docker container?

Comment: 1) There is no reverse of a bind mount. It already works both ways. It is how one usually solves the problem you have: keeping files persistent over multiple runs of a container.

2) You cannot run that command from inside a container, it breaks isolation, security and whatnot. I would recommend shutting down the container via script from your host and execute the copy before that. Or do the (imo) proper way and use a bind mount.