# How to configure docker-compose to run a specific Docker command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was required to copy files from ubuntu container to host machine. So I found a way to do that using `docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target` command. I able to use this command while I am not in the ubuntu conainer, i.e., when I am not `docker exec` mode.

My problem is I want to know how to run Docker commands from Dockerfile, so that on/before exiting from the ubuntu container, the docker command should run which will copy the content from container to host.

I mightn't be able to do it with CMD[ ] as it would be docker inside docker container.

Any help would be very appreciable.

Here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
    ubuntu:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: ubuntu
        ports:
            - 8091
        volumes:
            - ./dir:/dir
volumes:
    dir:
        external: false
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /dir
VOLUME /dir

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y

EXPOSE 8000
COPY . .
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**Edit 1:**
I tried implementing my [Original Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036363/sync-files-from-docker-container-to-host-using-dockerfile-or-docker-compose) using bind mount this way. But this way too it is not syncing the folders

```
version: '3'
services:
    ubuntu:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: ubuntu
        ports:
            - 8091
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./dir
              target: /dir
volumes:
    dir:
        external: false
```

Comment: To a first approximation, you can't run `docker` commands from inside a container, and you especially can't run them from a Dockerfile.  What leads to this very specific flow; have you looked at other approaches for example involving Docker bind mounts?

Comment: (The Dockerfile you show doesn't really contain anything; do you have a more complete setup that installs an application and sets the `CMD` to run that process rather than an interactive shell?  I would not normally expect to use an unmodified `ubuntu` image, nor would I expect the default command in a container to be a shell.)

Comment: Hello again, you cannot run a `docker ...` command from a Dockerfile, since the Dockerfile is host-agnostic and does not help building the image. Since I know your [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036363/sync-files-from-docker-container-to-host-using-dockerfile-or-docker-compose), follow the recommendation of @DavidMaze: use a bind mount.

Comment: @DavidMaze No I haven't used bind mounts. As far as I have read about bind mounts.... isn't it used to mount a file or directory from the host machine to the container? Like the actual thing is that I want to copy/sync files from container to host, so that my host remains updated to whatever work I am doing in container

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent Alright. Will do some more research on it and would try to implement it

Comment: The bind mount is **constantly** "synchronizing" the shared directory. So no extra action needed on container shutdown, it happens in real time. Only drawback is that it is somewhat slow to read/write, so if your work is I/O intensive, you have to run a command **inside** the container on termination to copy your files to the bind mounted directory.

Comment: @OneFullTimeEquivalent I tried implementing bind mount, but it seems like it is not synchronising the data. I have update the question and have added my updated docker-compose file in Edit 1 Section. Please check and do let me know if I am making any mistake here.

Comment: As I said in the other question, I believe you do not need the top-level `volumes` declaration. I don't know how else to help you, it's usually a very simple thing, but I am not too familiar with compose.